# wrap a promise within a promise returning method output

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, promise

I have below function

```
const initSync = () => {
  return localDB
    .sync(remoteDB, {
      live: true,
      retry: true
    })
    .on('change', function(change) {
      if (change.direction === 'pull') {
        console.log(change.change.docs) //this worked
        return change.change.docs
      }
    })
}
```

I want to call it somewhere

I do `const result = await initSync()`, but in `result` I get nothing, I feel strange, should I wrap it with a promise for above function?

Comment: Not knowing anything about your framework, but `.on()` sounds like an add Event Listener method, that's quite rare these return Promises.

Comment: there's never any point in returning a value from a `on` handler, since it gets discarded, since there's nothing to return a value **to**  (because, as noted above, it's an event listener) ... knowing this, you should be able to figure out your mistake

Comment: short answer, in the above case it actually does make sense to wrap the code in a `new Promise` - however, I'd still be looking at a different solution, personally - by the way, there's no evidence of any Promise at all in that code

Comment: @JaromandaX https://pouchdb.com/api.html#sync, how can I not connecting to the db and use `on` in multiple places?

Comment: @Kaiido so what should I do? chain the .on at somewhere else? like `initSync.on('change' => {})` ??

Comment: as I said, wrap it in a Promise ... seeing as there's not Promise already anyway, it's not like you'll have that Promise with a Promise you're worried about ... https://jsfiddle.net/9rjboxgf/

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to wrap event based systems in Promises, but if you're sure that the next event will indeed be for you, then `const initSync = () => new Promise(resolve => localDB
    .sync([...].direction === 'pull') { resolve (change.change.docs) })`